# Finding vertex and value of a in a function.

Tags: functions

Let $f(x) = a(x-h)^2 + k$.
The vertex of the graph of *f* is at $(2,3)$ and the graph passes through $(1,7)$.

a. Write down the value of $h$ and of $k$.

I know that $h$ and $k$ are the vertex, so I’m assuming that $h=2$ and $k=3$, but that seems like too simple of an answer so I’m worried that I am missing something here.

b. Find the value of $a$.

If I find the $h$ and $k$ values in part $a$, and I know $y = 7$ and $x = 1$, can I simply plug in all those values and solve for $a$?

Comment: $y=7$ at $x=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, why not:  $7=a(1-2)^2+3\implies 7=a(1)+3\implies a=4$...

You're on the right track.